# Express block matrix in terms of matrix basis

Tags: matrix, pattern-matching, group-theory

I'm trying to construct a function that returns the multiplication table of a matrix Lie algebra. Assuming a basis of matrices, my definitions:

```
Commutator[A_, B_] := A.B - B.A;
MultiplicationTable[basis_] :=  Outer[Commutator[#1, #2] &, basis, basis, 1]
```

yield a matrix comprising smaller matrices of numbers. The final step would be to rewrite this matrix, so that it is expressed in terms of the basis matrices. This is not a simple find-and-replace rule, because multiples of a matrix cannot be found this way. Any help is welcome.

## Example

The Lie algebra so(2,1) is generated by

```
 H = {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
 E1 = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
 E2 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
 Basis = {H, E1, E2};
```

and the output of `MultiplicationTable` is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 0& 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1& 0\end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 0& 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 0& 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I would like the output to be in the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -E2 & E1\\ E2 & 0 & H\\ -E1 & -H &0 \end{pmatrix},$$ because the multiplication table of algebras of higher dimension quickly becomes huge.

Comment: examples might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note, it's best practice to use lowercase symbols to avoid conflicts with builtins.)

```
multiplicationTable[basis_] := 
 Outer[LinearSolve[Transpose[Flatten /@ basis], 
    Flatten[commutator[##]]] &, basis, basis, 1]
```

If we turn each matrix in the `basis` and the `commutator` into a vector, we can find a linear combination of `basis` elements that equal the `commutator` using standard linear algebra (in this case, `LinearSolve`).

```
multiplicationTable[basis]

(* {
    {{0,  0, 0}, { 0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}},
    {{0,  0, 1}, { 0, 0,  0}, {1, 0, 0}},
    {{0, -1, 0}, {-1, 0,  0}, {0, 0, 0}}
   } *)
```

If you want to see the sum as an expression, we can `Dot` with a string representation of the basis (if we just used `basis` we'd end up with your original expression):

```
multiplicationTable[basis].{"H", "E1", "E2"} // MatrixForm

(* 0 -E2 E1
  E2   0  H
 -E1   H  0 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I was looking for. Please check my answer and feel free to add the changes I made to yours, so that I accept yours and delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially 2012rcampion's answer using `Association` for `Basis`. The definitions are:

```
 commutator[A_, B_] := A.B - B.A;
 multiplicationTable[basis_] := Outer[LinearSolve[Transpose[Flatten /@  Values[basis]], 
      Flatten[commutator[#1, #2]]] &, Values@basis, Values@basis, 1].Keys[basis]
```

and the basis:

```
 Basis = Association["H" -> H, "E1" -> E1, "E2" -> E2];
```

yielding

```
 multiplicationTable[Basis] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\text{E2} & \text{E1} \\ \text{E2} & 0 & \text{H} \\
 -\text{E1} & -\text{H} & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Further definitions useful for study of group theory:

```
 adjoint[X_, basis_] := Outer[Normalize[Flatten[#1]]\[Conjugate].Normalize[
         Flatten[commutator[X, #2]]] &, Values@basis, Values@basis, 1]
```

to obtain the *adjoint* or *regular representation* of a generator, and

```
 CKmetric[basis_] := Outer[Tr[adjoint[#1, basis].adjoint[#2, basis]] &,
          Values@basis, Values@basis, 1]
```

to obtain the *Cartan-Killing metric*.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more efficient way to compute your `MultiplicationTable` itself but as a post-processing measure you could use something like this:

```
rules = Join[
   Thread[Basis -> {"H", "E1", "E2"}],
   Thread[-Basis -> {"-H", "-E1", "-E2"}],
   {m_ /; MatrixQ[m, # == 0 &] :> 0}
  ];

Replace[MultiplicationTable[Basis], rules, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{0, "-E2", "E1"}, {"E2", 0, "H"}, {"-E1", "-H", 0}}
> ```

You could use [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) rather than strings if you wish to reuse the output by way of [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html).

Comment: You can half the number of matrix multiplications by using `# - Transpose[#] & [Outer[Dot, basis, basis, 1]]`

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided here are good.  But I would lean towards using group-theoretic properties rather than just a `LinearSolve`.

```
innerProduct[a_,b_]:=1/2 Tr[ConjugateTranspose[a].b] (* Usually *)
groupSolve[basis_,names_][matrix_]:=Total[MapThread[
    innerProduct[#1,matrix] #2 &,{basis,names}
    ]]
```

which then can be used with

```
multiplicationTable[basis_, names_]:=Outer[groupSolve[basis,names][Commutator[#1,#2]]&,
    basis,basis,1]
```

via `multiplicationTable[Basis,{"H","E1","E2"}]`.

Comment: Would you mind including reasoning or examples to support your position that this is superior?

Comment: Mainly:  if you have additional information about the problem, why not use it?  I don't have a claim that it's superior.  But it's how I would have solved the problem, given knowledge that it was a problem of group theory.